# Vue Way of Adding Detail content Row Dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue Calendar that I'm working on. When a day is clicked, I would like to open a full-width box under the week of the selected day that displays details of the day (Think Google Images layout) I know how to pass data in Vue, but how do I add this details (component, view?) under the row of the current week? (See my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/NjegpE)

```
<div class="calendar">
        <div class="header z-depth-2">
            <a @click="lastMonth" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">chevron_left</i>Last Month</a>
            <p>{{month}} {{year}}</p>
            <a @click="nextMonth" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">chevron_right</i>Next Month</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="dates month">
                    <li class="dow" v-for="dow in days">{{dow}}</li>
            <li v-for="blank in firstDayOfMonth" class="day"></li>
            <li v-for="date in daysInMonth" @click="openday(date)"
                class="day" :class="{'today': date == initialDate && month == initialMonth && year == initialYear}">
                <span>{{date}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
    el: '.calendar',
    data: {
        today: moment(),
    dateContext: moment(),
    days: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    },
    methods:{
        nextMonth: function () {
        var t = this;
        t.dateContext = moment(t.dateContext).add(1, 'month');
    },
    lastMonth: function () {
        var t = this;
        t.dateContext = moment(t.dateContext).subtract(1, 'month');
    }
    },
    computed: {
        year: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.dateContext.format('YYYY');
    },
    month: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.dateContext.format('MMMM');
    },
        daysInMonth: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.dateContext.daysInMonth();
    },
    currentDate: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.dateContext.get('date');
    },
    firstDayOfMonth: function () {
        var t = this;
        var firstDay = moment(t.dateContext).subtract((t.currentDate - 1), 'days');
        return firstDay.weekday();
    },
    //Previous Code Above
   initialDate: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.today.get('date');
    },
    initialMonth: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.today.format('MMMM');
    },
    initialYear: function () {
        var t = this;
        return t.today.format('YYYY');
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have no concept of a row (you just auto-wrap), you can't really insert a box that takes up a row. What I've done here is insert a div that is positioned `absolute`ly, so that I can make it full width, but it overlays the rows below, rather than shifting them out of the way.

If you rework it to have weeks, you could insert a detail box between weeks.

The basic working, though, is that you set a data item for the currently selected date when you click on a date, and you clear that item to dismiss the detail box (a click in the detail box does it, here). The HTML is controlled by a `v-if`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.calendar',
  data: {
    today: moment(),
    dateContext: moment(),
    days: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    selectedDate: null
  },
  methods: {
    nextMonth: function() {
      var t = this;
      t.dateContext = moment(t.dateContext).add(1, 'month');
    },
    lastMonth: function() {
      var t = this;
      t.dateContext = moment(t.dateContext).subtract(1, 'month');
    },
    openday(date) {
      this.selectedDate = date;
    },
    dismiss() {
      this.selectedDate = null;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    year: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.dateContext.format('YYYY');
    },
    month: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.dateContext.format('MMMM');
    },
    daysInMonth: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.dateContext.daysInMonth();
    },
    currentDate: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.dateContext.get('date');
    },
    firstDayOfMonth: function() {
      var t = this;
      var firstDay = moment(t.dateContext).subtract((t.currentDate - 1), 'days');
      return firstDay.weekday();
    },
    //Previous Code Above
    initialDate: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.today.get('date');
    },
    initialMonth: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.today.format('MMMM');
    },
    initialYear: function() {
      var t = this;
      return t.today.format('YYYY');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: #222222;
}

.calendar {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100vw;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

.fade-enter {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.next {
  animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.next {
  animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.prev {
  animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.prev {
  animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dates {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.day {
  width: 14%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dow {
  width: 14%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  color: teal;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.detail-panel {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  height: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.today {
  color: teal;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.day-name {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}

.day-number {
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="header z-depth-2">
    <a @click="lastMonth" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">chevron_left</i>Last Month</a>
    <p>{{month}} {{year}}</p>
    <a @click="nextMonth" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">chevron_right</i>Next Month</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dates month">
    <li class="dow" v-for="dow in days">{{dow}}</li>
    <li v-for="blank in firstDayOfMonth" class="day"></li>
    <li v-for="date in daysInMonth" class="day" :class="{'today': date == initialDate && month == initialMonth && year == initialYear}">
      <span @click="openday(date)">{{date}}</span>
      <div class="detail-panel" v-if="selectedDate === date" @click="dismiss">Hi there I see you selected {{date}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I took your advice and am adding functionality for `week` now as I think that will allow the best display. Thanks!

Comment: Would you have a recommended method for selecting a week? In plain JS I'd probably do something like get the first selector `week`. Is there a more Vue way to do that?

Comment: Your data should be organized by week, so you should be able to do something like `v-if="week.includes(selectedDate)"`